# N1QL Array Query for where condition to check inner elament

Tags: json, node.js, couchbase, sql++

I have JSON like below

```
{
  "_id": "000fad10-b2de-11e6-92de-632a9b1d21d9",
  "_type": "Company",
  "status": 1,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "completed": 1,
      "currency": "USD",
      "date": "2015-12-01T18:30:00.000Z",
      "method": 0,
      "type": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to run like below query

```
select * from MyBucket where transactions.method in (0,3);
```

How can I do it in N1QL ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyBucket WHERE ANY x IN transactions SATISFIES x.method in[1,0] END;
```

I get answer by this

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyBucket b UNNEST b.transactions t WHERE t.method in [0,3];
```

keep this [cheatsheet](http://docs.couchbase.com/files/Couchbase-N1QL-CheatSheet.pdf)

Comment: I miss the "[ ]" at in. Using your query I get 4 total json.
 But I have only 3. in One json I have 2 transaction.

Comment: No need to UNNEST: SELECT * FROM MyBucket WHERE transactions.method IN [0,3];

Comment: can you see this question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838443/want-to-sum-inner-element-with-json-in-using-n1qlcouchbase